# Replace splice with filter

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, filter

I haven't had too many opportunities to use `filter()` yet but I decided to a bit shorten my code, unfortunately It doesn't work as I wish it to be. I have written function to remove element from the array in good old fashion way which works nice:

```
this.error_log.map((error, i) => {
                if (error.message.info == message) {
                    this.error_log.splice(i, 1)
                }
            })
```

it works pretty well actually but I wanted to rewrite it to filter, unfortunately it doesn't work and I have no idea why, could anyone explain me what am I doing wrong here?

```
this.error_log.filter(error => error.message.info !== message)
```

Comment: looks ok. What you received?

Comment: `.filter` does not mutate the array. `map` doesn't either but your're doing a `splice` which indeed modifies the array. `filter` returns a result. Use `this.error_log = this.error_log.filter(error => error.message.info !== message)`.

Comment: Please always check the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) first. The very first sentence says "The **filter()** method **creates a new array**"

Comment: Please avoid using things like `.map` to simply go over the array. Each of the array iteration methods has a *purpose* and a *meaning* - using them just to loop while disregarding when and why they should be used, is definitely not good code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
this.error_log = this.error_log.filter(error => error.message.info !== message);
```

Comment: eh so that was the problem... Anyway it works:) I will mark it as an answer in 12 min, Thanks!